# Find the limit $\lim_{x \to 0} \left( 1 + \sin \left( \frac 3 x \right) \right)^x$

Tags: limits

What is the answer to the limit?
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \left( 1 + \sin \left( \frac 3 x \right) \right)^x$$
The book's answer shows that $e^3$ while I keep getting $e^0$. I used the estimation
$$\lim_{x \to 0} x \ln x \le \lim_{x \to 0} x \ln \left( 1 + \sin \left( \frac 3 x \right) \right) \le 0$$

Comment: Should the limit be as $x\to\infty$? As stated, the limit is $1$.

Comment: No, this stupid limit is $x\to 0$

Comment: That must be a typo. The limit is $e^3$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: $\sin \frac 3x$ does not converge to $+\infty$ as $x\to 0$

Comment: @BrianTung probably

Comment: You need $x\to 0+$, because when $\sin(3/x)=-1$ you get $0^{x}$, which is undefined when $x<0$.

Comment: Perhaps it's $3/\sin(x)$ instead of $\sin(3/x)$?

Comment: But it seems like it is likely undefined, since there is always a zero value and always a value close to $1$.

Comment: @leonbloy no, probably this is a typo.

Comment: but we have $x$ tends to zero, or not?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews [Mathematica](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit%5B%281+%2B+Sin%5B3%2Fx%5D%29%5Ex%2C+x+-%3E+0%5D) evaluates the limit as $1$.

Comment: for $x$ tends to zero we get $1$ as the searched limit

Comment: The limit doesn't exist since the functions takes on values of $0$ and $1$ in all $(0,\epsilon)$.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner could you tell me more "searched limit is"?

Comment: @A.S. thanks I understand your logic and convinced!! Perhaps you can add it as answer.

Comment: do we have $x$ tends to $0$ or $x$ tends to $\infty$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner $x\to0$ as typo on book. Still I was having hard time believing that limit does not exist for above question.

Comment: yes $e^3$ is the right answer

Comment: Good for mathematica. Doesn't make it right @MulaKoSaag

Comment: @ThomasAndrews haha yes. I was deceived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick a fixed  $\alpha\geq 0$. Let $a=e^{-2\pi\alpha/3}$.

Pick $u_n\in(0,\pi/2)$ so that $\sin u_n =1-a^n$.

Then define $x_n=\frac{3}{2n\pi - u_n}$.

Then $1+\sin(3/x_n)=a^n$, and $(a^n)^x=e^{-\frac{2\pi n\alpha}{2n\pi+u_n}}$

So $x_n\to 0$, and $\frac{2\pi n}{2n\pi+u_n}\to 1$, so 
$$\left(1+\sin\left(\frac3{x_n}\right)\right)^{x_n}\to e^{-\alpha}$$

So the above limit cannot exist. It has all of $[0,1]$ as limit points.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is there's a typo in the question. As $x\to\infty$, we have $$\left(1+\sin\left(\frac3x\right)\right)^x\to\exp\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}x\sin\left(\frac3x\right)\right)=e^3.$$
As pointed out in the comments, the limit as $x\to0$ does not exist.